# How to get Video Input

Tags: fpga, video, display

I help maintain an old beaten down LED sign on the side of a highway.

Right it has a program running on Win98 to generate the image that should be on the sign (FLASH animation, temperature, etc), and drive a PCI IO card which in turn drives the sign logic. I'd like to (be able to) replace the control package of the sign with something less painful.

A different sign we're working on has a DVI input to a control board. The control board takes a specific portion of the video and sends it off to the sign. I like this scheme because it makes it easier to change out the computer if it breaks, and allows a lot of freedom in terms of what software/hardware can be used- so long as a PC has a DVI port, it can drive the sign.

Core Question: How can I go from 'video input' to a copy of what is on the screen for consumption by digital logic?

The one thing I've come up with so far is using a [TFP401A](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/tfp401a.html), and feeding that into an FPGA where a lot of accompanying logic would sit.

Does that seem reasonable? Is there a better way? At least one concern is that I don't have any experience with high frequency design- I'm not certain how much care needs to be taken on the traces between DVI connector and receiver, as well as from receiver to FPGA.

**EDIT:**

Few added details:

- The sign is low resolution (47x127 image, 24x64 sign)
- It displays animation (refresh rate > 10Hz)
- I'd prefer something without dependence on software on the PC (suggests taking a video signal of some format)
- This is 80% learning experience- while the goal is a practical replacement system, I would like to end with the knowledge of how this can be done.

Comment: Do you know for certain that the DVI input really expects the same signals from a PC DVI output?  The connector may simply be a DVI connector, but not actually accept conventional DVI PC monitor signals.

Comment: The input on the other sign controller? Yes- there's a straight connection from the output of the video card to the DVI-IN on the controller; comes up as a monitor in windows, etc; video card is a cheap card ordered from newegg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental question here is how fast you need to update the sign's image.

If you don't need to update it more often than once every few seconds, DVI is WAAAAAY overkill. (And placing something that shows video next to a highway seems like a very bad idea)

You're probably best off using a frame-buffer in your hardware, and using something like a [FT232](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm) or [FT245](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT245R.htm) to dump images to it.  The FT2** IC Gives you ~8 MBps of interface bandwith over USB, and a dead-easy software driver you can talk to.

Alternatively, depending on your sign's resolution, you could use a simple serial interface.

I would assume you would be sending raw bitmaps to the sign (it makes the software end easier). Then you just cache them in the hardware, and then serve them up to whatever interface the sign implements from your hardware.

Comment: Part of the existing sign is animation, so it needs to update on the order of 10's of Hz. That said, the resolution of the sign is on the order of 24x64, so, sending over by one of FTDI chips would work. But I would prefer something with no explicit dependence on PC software.

Comment: Serial ports are serial ports. The FTDI devices are just a convenient way to add one.

Comment: Anyways, a 47*127 image @ 10 hz, with 8 bits per pixel (could be more, I doubt it) is only 477520 baud, so you could do it with a generic serial interface.

Comment: Besides, this is assuming the animation does not loop. If your display is a static sequence of x frames (30, 60, etc... even with 24 bit color, each frame would only be 17.9 kb) which repeat, you could just buffer those in the controller, and update them asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

How about something simpler?

Perhaps a compact flash card with a bitmap image file or GIF89a on it?
A microcontroller could read the card and drive the display.

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't think it would work well for the 'time/temperature' basics though, and there'd still need to be a way to easily update the sign (asking a Bank Manager to get on a ladder, open the sign and replace an SD card wouldn't work; wireless update could be done).

Answer (score 0):

Decoding DVI is going to be tricky - some cards provide digital+analog, while some only provide digital outputs. And resolution can of course vary.

I think you'd be better off with a simple serial interface that you could connect to the computer to and send commands, e.g. "turn LED 3,4 on red", "draw this sprite", "clear screen"...